# Позиционирование текса по центру в эллипсах

Tags: html, css, текст, background, центрирование

Почему у меня текст выстроен не по центру эллипсов? Эллипсы это изображения. Текст выравнивается почему то только по первой строке. Но как сделать, чтобы он был строго по центру эллипса в каждом блоке?
[image: Результат]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Header*/

header {
  width: 1350px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header__feedback {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.header__logo {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.header__menu_list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__feedback_icon img {
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.header__feedback_items {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 156px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #2f1059;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 38px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.header__feedback_button a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header__feedback_number {
  color: #2f1059;
}

.header__menu_list_item1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.header__menu_list_item2,
.header__menu_list_item3,
.header__menu_list_item4,
.header__menu_list_item5 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}


/* Header END*/


/* Section1*/

section {
  width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.section1 {
  background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center top scroll;
  padding: 1px;
  min-height: 600px;
}

.section1__heading_paragraph_up {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.section1__heading_paragraph_down {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.section1__heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 75px;
  color: #2f1059;
}

.section1__heading h1 {
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section1__head {
  width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* form*/

.form {
  background: url(../img/form.png) no-repeat center top;
  width: 920px;
  height: 378px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 165px auto 0 auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.form__head {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fbfafa;
}

.form__head p {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.form__block {
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.form__input1 {
  width: 201px;
  height: 51px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.form__input2 {
  width: 201px;
  height: 51px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.form__button {
  width: 274px;
  height: 51px;
  background: #d22828;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.form__footer {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #7925ec;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.form__footer span {
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #7925ec;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}


/* form END*/


/* Преимущества*/

.advantages ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 150px;
}

.advantages li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: url(../img/ellipse.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 153px;
  width: 153px;
  height: 153px;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 32px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 45px;
}

.advantages__list span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.advantages__item1 {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.advantages li:nth-child(3),
.advantages li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: -135px;
}

.advantages li:nth-child(2),
.advantages li:nth-child(5) {
  margin-top: -68px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}


/* Преимущества END*/


/* Section1 END*/


/* Section2*/
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="header__logo">
      <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="header__menu_list">
      <ul>
        <li class="header__menu_list_item1"><a href="#">Инфраструктура</a></li>
        <li class="header__menu_list_item2"><a href="#">Планировки и цены</a></li>
        <li class="header__menu_list_item3"><a href="#">Материалы и отделка</a></li>
        <li class="header__menu_list_item4"><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
        <li class="header__menu_list_item5"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header__feedback">
      <div class="header__feedback_number">
        + 7 (495) 544-23-12
      </div>
      <div class="header__feedback_items">
        <div class="header__feedback_icon">
          <img src="img/icon_phone.png" alt="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="header__feedback_button">
          <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="section1">
  <div class="section1__head">
    <div class="section1__heading">
      <p class="section1__heading_paragraph_up">
        <span>Дом готов</span> идет внутренняя отделка. Срок сдачи: <span>Февраль 2016</span>
      </p>
      <h1>Ваша квартира в новостройке ждет вас</h1>
      <p class="section1__heading_paragraph_down">Уютные квартиры в центре города и в <span>5 минутых от р. Волга</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form__head">
      Запишитесь на просмотр прямо сейчас!
      <p>
        Покажем Вам квартиры в удобное для Вас время
      </p>
    </div>
    <form class="form__block" action="#">
      <input class="form__input1" type="text" method "post" placeholder="Имя">
      <input class="form__input2" type="tel" method "post" placeholder="Телефон">
      <button class="form__button" type="submit">Записаться на просмотр!</button>
    </form>
    <div class="form__footer">Осталось всего <span>5</span> квартир!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="advantages">
    <ul class="advantages__list clearfix">
      <li class="advantages__item1"><span>5 минут</span> до центра</li>
      <li class="advantages__item2"><span>300 метров</span> до Волги</li>
      <li class="advantages__item3"><span>Экологически чистое</span> место</li>
      <li class="advantages__item4"><span>Бесплатная кладовка</span> в подвале</li>
      <li class="advantages__item5"><span>Бесплатное парковочное место</span></li>
      <li class="advantages__item"><span>Бюджетная отделка под ключ</span> въехал и живи</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section2">
  <div class="section2__head">
    <h2>Дом готов. Идет внутренняя отделка</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="img.icon.png" alt="icon"> Срок сдачи: Февраль 2016
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ну а что вас смущает? Все как по макету который вы постили.

Comment: @midia, нее. В макете надписи строго по центру. А у меня получилось так, что текст выше центра. На первом эллипсе хорошо это видно.

Comment: @Максим Ленский , честно говоря ничего не понял.. Я только учусь верстать. Это первый макет и хотелось бы по максимуму "пиксель в пиксель" сделать..

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, имеете ввиду экспортировать картинкой сразу с текстом?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский это мне еще явно рано делать)) Я еще толком не понимаю)) Мне бы понять как через CSS это сделать. И можно ли вообще.. В таком случае мне проще будет картинкой экспортировать из фотошопа..

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ок.

Comment: @Roman, решение на флексах вам подойдет ?

Comment: ответ дали - отметьте решением , Геннадий отлично сделал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый оптимальный способ выровнять что-нибудь в вёрстке вертикально по центру на сегодняшний день - `css flex`;

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding:15px;
}


/* Преимущества*/

.advantages__list{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  margin:0 -10px;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.advantages__item{
  padding:20px;
  width:140px;
  min-height:140px;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  margin:0 10px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at center, yellow 70px,transparent 70px);
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
/*****************Тут начинается магия***************/
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  /*Важно! При таком способе позиционирования у .advantages__item должен быть только один непосредственный потомок, иначе flex выстроит их(потомков) в линию */
}
/*Тут магия заканчивается и начинается позиционирование "лесекнкой"*/
.advantages__item:first-child,
.advantages__item:last-child{
  margin-top:60px;
}
.advantages__item:nth-child(2),
.advantages__item:nth-child(5){
  margin-top:30px;
}
/*Бонусный хвост*/
.advantages__item:before{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:20px solid yellow;
  border-top:14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:14px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 14px);
  left:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages">
  <ul class="advantages__list clearfix">
    <li class="advantages__item"><span><b>5 минут</b> до центра</span></li>
    <li class="advantages__item"><span><b>300 метров</b> до Волги</span></li>
    <li class="advantages__item"><span><b>Экологически чистое</b> место</span></li>
    <li class="advantages__item"><span><b>Бесплатная кладовка</b> в подвале</span></li>
    <li class="advantages__item"><span><b>Бесплатное парковочное место</b></span></li>
    <li class="advantages__item"><span><b>Бюджетная отделка под ключ</b> въехал и живи</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Получилось